# Basic calculus limit to infinity problem including sin and cot that my teacher told us not to solve.

Tags: calculus, limits

my calculus teacher told us to not solve this problem but I gave it a try, and I failed miserably as the $\lim_{x\to ∞}$ for the sin is ∞. **I'm supposed to bring the formula to a L'hopital expression at some point**

Here's the problem:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to ∞} (1+\sin(4x))^{\cot(x)}$$

I've tried applying natural logarithm in order to take the cot as a factor, but then I still have the issue that goes to infinity and beyond:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to ∞} e^{ln(1+\sin(4x))^{\cot(x)}}$$
so then:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to ∞} e^{ln(1+\sin(4x))* \color{red}{\cot(x)}}$$

After this point I tried converting the $\color{red}{\cot(x)}$ to $\color{red}{\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}}$ and tried to operate from there, but I got really stuck due to the $\lim_{x\to ∞}$.

Anyways, I'll leave this here, I hope to find the answer myself before but I might get lucky with someone here.

Comment: Thing 1:  $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin(x)$ isn't $\infty$.

Comment: If $x=2n\pi-\pi/8,$ then $(1+\sin(4x))^{\cot x}=0$

Comment: @Randall Isn't sin a periodic function that goes from 1 to 0 and if I make x tend to ∞ I just get or 1 or 0? Like, it's undefined? it's 1? it's 0?

Comment: The limit does not exist.  It does not tend to $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit.

$$f(x) =(1+\sin(4x))^{\cot x}$$

is periodic with period $\pi$. $f$ is also not a constant function; $f(3\pi/8 )=0$, $f(\pi/2) = 1$.

Comment: So that's the answer to the problem, there is no constant limit?

Comment: There is no limit.

Comment: I see, and the justification would be because it is a trigonometric function that doesn't have a defined value in the infinity to be called a limit, is that enough?

Comment: No, it is because it is periodic and not constant.

Comment: I see, thanks Jeffery.